# How I can get proper public keys for apple signin

Tags: jwk

I'm trying to implement apple signin and get a token from appleid provider and i've found out the `jwks-client` can do the trick but I can't get necessary keys. For some reason it returns nothing as a public key. What uri I need to use to get public keys?

```
const kid = JSON.parse(header).kid;

const jwksClient = require('jwks-client');
const client = jwksClient({
    jwksUri: // what do i need to use?
});

client.getSigningKey(kid, (err, key) => {
    // no key returned
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys` as stated on the apple dev portal [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/fetch_apple_s_public_key_for_verifying_token_signature)